# breeze validationErrorsChanged don't work with custom validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, validation, breeze

In directive I subscribe at validationErrorsChanged event. But wwhen I change data at page. Events works only standart type validation.

Standart **required** validation

```
<input class="form-control input-xs" type="text" required
                       data-ng-model="item.Description" data-entity-errors-indicator="item.Description">
```

Customer validation **FlowValidation**

```
div data-eve-compartment-and-technosphere-flow-selector="item"
                        data-eve-compartment="Compartment"
                        data-eve-compartment-id="CompartmentID"
                        data-eve-technosphere-flow="TechnosphereFlow"
                        data-eve-technosphere-flow-id="TechnosphereFlowID"
                        data-eve-data-source="ActivityModel.CompartmentsAndTechnosphereFlows"
                        class="pull-left"
                        data-entity-errors-indicator="item:FlowValidation" />
                </td>
```

Dirictive

```
.directive('entityErrorsIndicator', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var entity = scope.item;

            var propertyName;

            if (attrs.entityErrorsIndicator && attrs.entityErrorsIndicator.length > 0) {
                var item = attrs.entityErrorsIndicator.split('.');
                var methodValidate = attrs.entityErrorsIndicator.split(':');

                if (item.length > 1) {
                    propertyName = item[1];
                }

                if (methodValidate.length > 1) {
                    propertyName = methodValidate[1];
                }
            } else {
                propertyName = attrs.ngModel.split('.')[1];
            }

            element.attr('data-html', 'true');

            var unsubcribeTokens;

            unsubcribeTokens = entity.entityAspect.validationErrorsChanged.subscribe(function(event) {
                checkErrors();
            });

            checkErrors();

            function checkErrors() {
                var err = [];

                entity.entityAspect.validateEntity();

                if (propertyName != null) {
                        _.each(entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors(), function(e) {
                            var keyParts = e.key.split(':');
                            if (keyParts[1] === propertyName) {
                                err.push(e);
                            }
                        });
                }

                var $parent = element[0].tagName == "SPAN" || element[0].tagName == "DIV" ? element : element.parent();

                if (err.length > 0) {
                    $parent.addClass('has-error');
                    element.attr('data-original-title', getErrorsHtml(err));
                    element.tooltip('fixTitle');
                } else {
                    $parent.removeClass('has-error');
                    element.tooltip('hide').attr('data-original-title', null);
                }
            }

            function getErrorsHtml(errors) {
                if (errors.length == 1) {
                    return errors[0].errorMessage;
                }

                var str = "<ul>";
                _.each(errors, function (error) {
                    str += "<li>" + error.errorMessage + "</li>";
                });
                str += "</ul>";
                return str;
            }

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                if (unsubcribeTokens != null) {
                    entity.entityAspect.validationErrorsChanged.unsubscribe(unsubcribeTokens);
                }

            });
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't validate this.  We have many custom validators and validations in our test suite and none exhibit this behavior.  Take a look at the 'DocCode' sample in the breeze.js.samples GitHub repo to see examples of some of these.

I think you will need to isolate your Breeze validation code from the rest of your UI to verify this.

If you still think you have a bug, simply create a bug that fails ( within the DocCode structure) and then post the code either here or add a new issue to 'breeze.js.samples' repo here:

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples

Comment: Validate working only when in scope $watch use entity.entityAspect.validateEntity();